# Complexity measurement in algorithms using auto-initialized arrays

Tags: java, php, arrays, time-complexity

When it comes to evaluate the time complexity of an algorithm which uses an array that must be initialized, usually it is expressed as `O(k)`. Where *k* is the size of the array.
For instance, the *counting sort* has a time complexity of `O(n + k)`.

But what happend when the array is automatically initialized, like in Java or PHP. Would it be fair to say that the *counting sort* (or any other algorithm that needs an initialized array) in Java (or PHP...) has a time complexity of `O(n)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort which has an time complexity of O(n + k)?

You have to remember that time complexity is determined for an idealised machine which doesn't have caches, resource constraints and is independent of how a particular language or machine might actually perform.

The time complexity is still `O(n + k)`

However in a real machine that the initialisation is likely to much more efficient that the incrementing , so `n` and `k` are not directly comparable.  The pattern for initialisation is like to be sequential and very efficient (the `n`). If the counts are of type `int` for example, the CPU could be using `long` or 128-bit registers to perform the initialisation.

The access pattern for counting is likely to be relatively random and for large values of `k` likely to be much slower. (up to 10x slower)

Comment: But that is my point. What if that efficiency is enough to reduce complexity? (I corrected the complexity)

Answer (score 1):

actually it would be `O(n+k)`

thus if `n` is of a higher order than `k` (many duplicates in counting sort) it can be discarded in the time complexity making it `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Automatic initialization isn't *free*, you must account for it anyway, so it's still O(n + k).